# Why does my clear button only clear the text boxes if the validations are true?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

i am making a signup form and it has a clear button. the form has validations for all the text boxes to make sure they are true.

I have a clear button and it works but only if the validations are true which is not what i want, i would like it to clear no matter what, is there a way to do that?

here is my code for the event handler for the clear button

```
 protected void ImageButton2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {


        TextBoxEmail.Text = String.Empty;
        TextBoxEmail2.Text = String.Empty;
        TextBoxPassword1.Text = String.Empty;
        TextBoxPassword2.Text = String.Empty;
        TextBoxUsername.Text = String.Empty;
        TextBoxWebsite.Text = String.Empty;

    }
```

here is the other code for the webpage

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="Project5.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
<title>Sign Up Page</title>
<link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
    width: 100%;
}

    .auto-style3 {
    width: 402px;
    text-align: left;
}

.auto-style4 {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.auto-style6 {
    font-family: "comic Sans MS";
    color: #3366FF;
}

.validator {
    font-size: small;
    color: red;
}

.auto-style7 {
    width: 327px;
    text-align: center;
}

.auto-style8 {
    text-align: right;
}
    .auto-style9 {
        width: 402px;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<h1>
    <img src="Images/scccLogo.png" />
</h1>

<h2>
    Please register you SCCC account
</h2>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="auto-style8">
        <div>
        </div>
        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style7">
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelUsrName" runat="server" Text="Please 
Enter Your Username:" CssClass="auto-style6"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxUsername" runat="server" 
Width="185px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxUsername" CssClass="validator" 
ErrorMessage="* Please Enter A Username"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style7">
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelPassword" runat="server" 
Text="Please Enter Your Password:" CssClass="auto-style6"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxPassword1" runat="server" 
Width="185px" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" 
runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxPassword1" CssClass="validator" 
ErrorMessage="* Please Enter A Password"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style7">
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelPasswordRepeat" runat="server" 
Text="Please Enter Your Password Again:" CssClass="auto-style6"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxPassword2" runat="server" 
Width="185px" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" 
runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxPassword2" CssClass="validator" 
ErrorMessage="* Please Enter A Password"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" 
runat="server" ControlToCompare="TextBoxPassword1" 
ControlToValidate="TextBoxPassword2" CssClass="validator" ErrorMessage="* 
Passwords Do Not Match"></asp:CompareValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style7">
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelEmail" runat="server" Text="Please 
Enter A Valid Email Address:" CssClass="auto-style6"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEmail" runat="server" 
Width="185px" TextMode="Email"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" 
runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail" CssClass="validator" 
ErrorMessage="* Please Enter An Email"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail" CssClass="validator" ErrorMessage="* Please 
Enter A Valid Email" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+ 
([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style7">
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelEmail2" runat="server" Text="Please 
Enter Your Email Again:" CssClass="auto-style6"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEmail2" runat="server" 
Width="185px" TextMode="Email"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" 
runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail2" CssClass="validator" 
ErrorMessage="* Please Enter An Email"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" 
runat="server" ControlToCompare="TextBoxEmail" 
ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail2" CssClass="validator" ErrorMessage="* 
Emails Do Not Match"></asp:CompareValidator>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail2" CssClass="validator" ErrorMessage="* 
Please Enter A Valid Email" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+ 
([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style7">
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelWebsite" runat="server" Text="Please 
Enter Your Website" CssClass="auto-style6"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxWebsite" runat="server" 
CssClass="auto-style4" Width="185px" TextMode="Url"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="TextBoxWebsite" CssClass="validator" ErrorMessage="* 
Please Enter A Valid URL" ValidationExpression="http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+ 
(/[\w- ./?%&amp;=]*)?"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style7">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
CssClass="validator" Text="* Required Field"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style9">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonClear" runat="server" 
CssClass="auto-style4" Height="105px" ImageUrl="~/Images/32293367-red-clear- 
button.jpg" OnClick="ImageButton2_Click" Width="112px" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
ImageUrl="~/Images/go.jpg" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ImageButton causes validation, which is the default. I think you just have to add CausesValidation="false" attribute like this :

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonClear" runat="server" 
CssClass="auto-style4" Height="105px" ImageUrl="~/Images/32293367-red-clear- 
button.jpg" OnClick="ImageButton2_Click" CausesValidation="false" Width="112px" />
```

Cf. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.causesvalidation?view=netframework-4.7.2